# What are the API limits for the Google Search API for Shopping?

Tags: google-search-api, google-shopping-api

What are the API limits for the [Google Search API for Shopping](http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/search/)?

I read [here](http://blog.search-computing.net/2010/12/google-shopping-api/) that there is a limit of 2500 queries per day. However, I can't find any reference to the limits in the official documentation. Can anyone advise, or point to an authoritative source?

Comment: Google shopping is shutting down on the 16th of September http://shoppingapishutdown.com/ Disclosure: I work at Semantics3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google-search-api-for-shopping/browse_thread/thread/a71e04ae01c27044#) talks more about the limits.  Apparently it's a 'starter' plan of 2500 queries per day.  You can request to have that limit increased.

According to "Raz":

> Go to
>   https://code.google.com/apis/console/
>   .  On the left side is the  Traffic
>   Controls link where you can instantly
>   set you  requests/user/second and
>   request a higher daily per user quota.
>   Also,  on the same page it says the
>   default 2500 is per end user IP
>   address  which can be specified via a
>   request parameter.

Comment: Note that if the API url you're using includes `/public/` in the path (it's referred to as the "source"), you won't get a quota increase. You must either create a Commerce Search account (starts at $25k/year) or use the Google Affiliate Network. Making a mobile app? See: https://developers.google.com/shopping-search/forum/?place=topic%2Fgoogle-search-api-for-shopping%2F_78p3VulAxw%2Fdiscussion